# Does ReportProgress have to be done in the DoWork Background method in c#?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have an app that collects data on a list of videos. I want the progress and filenames to be updated in real time. Do I have to place all the code that examines those files in the bw_DoWork method?

Currently I have this method, but the bw.ReportProgress isn't working right.

```
private void GetMovieData(List<FileInfo> completeMovieList)
    {
        List<string> movieLists = new List<string>();

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo movie in completeMovieList)
        {
            counter++;
            string[] movieData = new string[3];

            bw.ReportProgress(counter / completeMovieList.Count);


            // get last modified date
            string movieLastModified = string.Concat(movie.LastWriteTime.Year + "/" + movie.LastWriteTime.Month + "/" + movie.LastWriteTime.Day);

            // get duation of video
            string lengthOfVideo = Program.GetDetails(movie);

            if (!movieListWithData.ContainsKey(movie.Name))
            {
                movieData[0] = lengthOfVideo;
                movieData[1] = movieLastModified;
                movieData[2] = movie.FullName;
                movieListWithData.Add(movie.Name, movieData);

            }

            movieLists.Add(movie.FullName + "|" + lengthOfVideo + "|" + movieLastModified);

        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> key in movieListWithData)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(key.Key + "|" + key.Value[0] + "|" + key.Value[1] + "|" + key.Value[2]);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(Program.movieTxtFileLocalPath, sb.ToString());
    }
```

My DoWork method looks like:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

            }
```

}

Comment: You're misusing the BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to place all the code that examines those files in the bw_DoWork method?

No, the code doesn't have to physically be there, but you have to **call** the code from DoWork. Currently your DoWork method isn't doing anything.

Also remember to set the property [`WorkerReportsProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx) to `true` on your `BackgroundWorker`. You can do this in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

```
        bw.ReportProgress(counter / completeMovieList.Count);
```

That's an integer division, 1 / 2 = 0, not 0.5.  Since counter will never be larger than Count, the expression always produces 0.  One possible fix is to calculate a percentage:

```
        bw.ReportProgress(100 * counter / completeMovieList.Count);
```